# Make a Consecutive row calculation in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data:

```
a<- c(1:10)
b<- c(10:1)
```

Now I want to make a Consecutive calculation (of variable length in this example 2)on both rows (a and b) and save the output in two separate lists(a and b).

> The calculation should look like the following:
>
> **for a:**
>
> (1+2)/2; (2+3)/2; (3+4)/2;...; (9+10)/2
>
> **for b(the same)**:
>
> (10+9)/2; (9+8)/2; (8+7)/2;...;(2+1)/2

```
a
1,5 2,5 3,5 ... 9,5
b
9,5 8,5 7,5 ... 1,5
```

I found this function in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200841/consecutive-rolling-sums-in-a-vector-in-r):

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30)
grp <- 3

res <- sapply(1:(length(v)-grp+1),function(x){sum(v[x:(x+grp-1)])})
```

Which pretty much does what i need but I would prefer a function which does that without using `sapply` and just base R.
Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do base `R`:

```
f = function(x) (head(x,-1) + tail(x,-1))/2

list(a=f(a), b=f(b))
#$a
#[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5

#$b
#[1] 9.5 8.5 7.5 6.5 5.5 4.5 3.5 2.5 1.5
```

Or if you want to use the `apply` family:

```
library(zoo)

list(a=rollapply(a,2, mean), b=rollapply(b,2, mean))
```

`sapply` **is really not recommended** but if you want to use it (**just for test!**):

```
sapply(1:(length(a)-1), function(i) mean(a[i:(i+1)]))
#[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5
#same for b
```

Comment: Pretty quick draw there

Comment: Too much vitamin this mornin'. Just luck actually.

Comment: Thank you! Just one question is it possible to adjust your fist answer so that I could choose how many Consecutive rows to sum up? So for example doing the same calculation like: `(1+2+3)2 ; (3+4+5)/2 etc.` .
I tried by setting -1 to -2 but that did not yield the right result.

Comment: use the `rollapply` function, it is far more simple in this case :)

Answer (score 3):

```
na.omit(filter(a, c(1,1))/2)
na.omit(filter(b, c(1,1))/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
d1 <- ((a + a[seq(a)+1])/2)[-length(a)]
#[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5
```

and

```
d2 <- ((b + b[seq(b)+1])/2)[-length(b)]
#[1] 9.5 8.5 7.5 6.5 5.5 4.5 3.5 2.5 1.5
```

The last part `[-length(a)]` and `[-length(b)]` removes `NA` entries at the end of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of `a` and `b` is same

```
for(i in 1:(length(a) - 1))
{
 list1[i] <- (a[i] + a[i+1])/2
 list2[i] <- (b[i] + b[i+1])/2
}
> list1
#[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5

> list2
#[1] 9.5 8.5 7.5 6.5 5.5 4.5 3.5 2.5 1.5
```

Or else write two different loops for both

```
for(i in 1:(length(a) - 1))
{
  list1[i] <- ((a[i] + a[i+1])/2)
}

for(i in 1:(length(b) - 1))
{
  list2[i] <- ((b[i] + b[i+1])/2)
}
```