# How to create column with sum of previous column's current row and row below using an apply function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I would like to be able to sum the value in each row with the value below and assign the result to a new column in R.

The following code (nearly) achieves what I want using a for loop (except that I have to manually do the last row - which is not really a problem). I would like to do a similar thing but using an apply function since the for loop is very slow on my large dataset - however I can't figure out the apply syntax.

```
data<-data.frame(runif(10))

data$x<-
 for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
   data[i,2 ] <- data[i,1]+data[i+1,1]
                          }
```

Comment: What does the last row sum with? Zero?

Comment: Make some research before asking questions. Question already exist [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200841/consecutive-rolling-sums-in-a-vector-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1). And read all the answer when pepole take time to answer to you before validate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the sum of the current value with the previous value by removing one value from either end of the column and conctenate with NA.

```
data$x <- c(data[,1][-1] + data[,1][-nrow(data)], NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use rollSum (package `RcppRoll`)

You can use the function `roll_sum(x, nb)` which allow you to do a (consecutive) rolling sum of a vector.

if we take your example:

```
data<-data.frame(x=runif(10000000))  
data$sum<-roll_sum(data$x, 1)
```

There is also the `rollapply(x, nb, fct)` from the package `zoo`but is less performant.

you can see a micro benchmark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200841/consecutive-rolling-sums-in-a-vector-in-r)

## Transform your data

Maybe just transforming you vector by creating a copy a him less the first value and with 0 on the last value will work.

```
data<-data.frame(x=runif(10))
data$copy<-c(data$x[-1],0)
data$sum<-rowSums(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a vector that is off by 1 (it starts from the second component) and add an NA at the end of it. Then do the sum.

```
data<-data.frame(runif(10))
col1 <- data$runif.10.
col1.off <- col1[2:length(col1)]
col1.off <- c(col1.off, NA)
data$x <- col1 + col1.off
```