# Consecutive Sum of a Vector

Tags: r, vector, cumsum, rollapply

This is a question following a previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200841/consecutive-rolling-sums-in-a-vector-in-r). In that question, it is suggested to use `rollapply` to calculate sum of the `1st, 2nd, 3rd` entry of a vector; then `2nd, 3rd, 4th`; and so on.

My question is how calculate sum of the `1st, 2nd and 3rd`; then the `4th, 5th and 6th`. That is, rolling without overlapping. Can this be easily done, please?

Answer (score 6):

Same idea. You just need to specify the by argument. Default is 1.

```
x <-c(1, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1)

zoo::rollapply(x, 3, by = 3, sum)
#[1] 10 20 12

#or another Base R option
sapply(split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/3)), sum)
# 1  2  3 
#10 20 12
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tapply` in base R:

```
set.seed(1)
vec <- sample(10, 20, replace = TRUE)
#[1]  3  4  6 10  3  9 10  7  7  1  3  2  7  4  8  5  8 10  4  8
unname(tapply(vec, (seq_along(vec)-1) %/% 3, sum))

# [1] 13 22 24  6 19 23 12
```

---

Alternatively,

```
colSums(matrix(vec[1:(ceiling(length(vec)/3)*3)], nrow = 3), na.rm = TRUE)

#[1] 13 22 24  6 19 23 12
```

`vec[1:(ceiling(length(vec)/3)*3)]` fills in the vector with `NA` if the length is not divisible by 3. Then, you simply ignore `NA`s in `colSums`.

---

Yet another one using `cut` and `aggregate`:

```
x <- ceiling(length(vec)/3)*3
df <- data.frame(vec=vec[1:x], col=cut(1:x, breaks = seq(0,x,3)))
aggregate(vec~col, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)[[2]]

#[1] 13 22 24  6 19 23 12
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define the window size, and do:

```
x <-c(1, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1)
n <- 3
diff(c(0, cumsum(x)[slice.index(x, 1)%%n == 0]))
```

p.s. using the input from the answer by @Sotos

Answer (score 1):

We can use `roll_sum` from `RcppRoll` which would be very efficient

```
library(RcppRoll)
roll_sum(x, n=3)[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)]
#[1] 10 20 12
```

#### data

```
x <-c(1, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1)
```