# How to calculate the mean of the previous 5 values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
agrodata

    week             temperature        humidity       radiation    evapotranspiration
   <date>                  <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
2012-03-25               15.9             54.1            20.4            0     
2012-06-17               25.9             65.6            22.2            0.486 
2012-06-24               27.4             61.7            21.3            0     
2012-07-08               27.5             62.9            22.4            0     
2012-07-15               27.5             50.1            23.1            0     
2012-07-22               27.0             56.4            19.0            0     
2012-07-29               28.7             61.5            19.7            0     
2012-08-05               29.1             56.1            20.0            0.0286
2012-08-12               28.6             56.8            19.4            0     
2012-08-19               29.0             63.0            18.1            0     
2012-08-26               27.4             62.9            18.0            0.229 
2012-09-02               16.9             32.9            16.9            0     
2012-09-09               25.0             62.1            16.7            0     
2012-09-16               25.4             62.6            14.5            0     
2012-09-30               22.3             65.6            15.2            0     
2012-10-07               22.4             71.4            13.9            0     
2012-10-14               19.3             67.2            11.3            0.257 
2012-10-21               18.7             74.5            9.70           3.43  
2012-10-28               16.4             75.5            8.35           3.2   
2012-11-04               17.8             79.7            7.17           7
```

As you can see I have the date grouped by weeks. I want to create 4 new columns (for each one of the 4 climate variables) containing the mean of the previous 5 consecutive weeks, and if there aren't 5 previous consecutive weeks, then whatever are... Is there some way to do it with dplyr? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consecutive/Rolling sums in a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200841/consecutive-rolling-sums-in-a-vector-in-r)

Comment: What happens when there are missing weeks?   Do we take all weeks between the current week and the week 5 weeks ago?  or only those between the last missing week in the last 5 weeks and the current week? or did you mean the previous 5 rows regardless of whether they are within 5 weeks or not? Is the current week included in the mean or is it strictly previous?

Comment: We take as much the 5 previous weeks. And we take all weeks between the current week and the week 5 weeks ago. If there aren't 5 previous weeks, we can take 4, or 3, or 2, or even 1 (the current week). The actual week is included, so we need the mean of 6 values (5 previous weeks and current week). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) rollapply**

Using `agroweek` shown in the Note at the end of this answer we assume that:

- the data in the question is representative, namely it is sorted by week and has no NAs. (It wouldn't be hard to relax these assumptions and in any case (2) allows NAs and unordered data.)
- what is wanted is the mean of all weeks within the last 6 weeks (as opposed to the last 6 rows)
- the last 6 weeks includes the current week

Use `findInterval` to find the row number of the week 6 weeks back and subtract that from the current row number to get, `width`, the vector holding the number of rows to average at each point.  Then use `rollapplyr` to calculate `r` the rolling means, prepend `mean_` to the column names and `cbind` them to the original data frame.  For another example, see the example involving `findInterval` in Examples section of `?rollapply`.

```
library(zoo)

k <- 6 # no of weeks
week <- agroweek$week
width <- seq_along(week) - findInterval(week - 7*k, week)
r <- rollapplyr(agroweek[-1], width, mean)
colnames(r) <- paste("mean", colnames(r), sep = "_")
res1 <- cbind(agroweek, r)
```

giving:

```
> head(res1)
        week temperature humidity radiation evapotranspiration mean_temperature mean_humidity mean_radiation mean_evapotranspiration
1 2012-03-25        15.9     54.1      20.4              0.000         15.90000        54.100       20.40000                  0.0000
2 2012-06-17        25.9     65.6      22.2              0.486         25.90000        65.600       22.20000                  0.4860
3 2012-06-24        27.4     61.7      21.3              0.000         26.65000        63.650       21.75000                  0.2430
4 2012-07-08        27.5     62.9      22.4              0.000         26.93333        63.400       21.96667                  0.1620
5 2012-07-15        27.5     50.1      23.1              0.000         27.07500        60.075       22.25000                  0.1215
6 2012-07-22        27.0     56.4      19.0              0.000         27.06000        59.340       21.60000                  0.0972
```

**2) SQL**

Another approach is a left self join in SQL grouping by week and averaging the joined values to each row.  This works even if there are NAs and even if the data is not sorted.

```
library(sqldf)

k <- 6
fn$sqldf("select a.*, 
    avg(b.temperature) as mean_temperature,
    avg(b.humidity) as mean_humidity,
    avg(b.radiation) as mean_radiation,
    avg(b.evapotranspiration) as mean_evapotranspiration 
  from agroweek as a
  left join agroweek as b on b.week between a.week - ($k-1)*7 and a.week
  group by a.week")
```

This could also be written as:

```
k <- 6
means <- toString(sprintf("avg(b.%s) as mean_%s", names(DF)[-1], names(DF)[-1]))
fn$sqldf("select a.*, $means
  from agroweek as a
  left join agroweek as b on b.week between a.week - ($k-1)*7 and a.week
  group by a.week")
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
agroweek <- structure(list(week = structure(c(15424, 15508, 15515, 15529, 
15536, 15543, 15550, 15557, 15564, 15571, 15578, 15585, 15592, 
15599, 15613, 15620, 15627, 15634, 15641, 15648), class = "Date"), 
    temperature = c(15.9, 25.9, 27.4, 27.5, 27.5, 27, 28.7, 29.1, 
    28.6, 29, 27.4, 16.9, 25, 25.4, 22.3, 22.4, 19.3, 18.7, 16.4, 
    17.8), humidity = c(54.1, 65.6, 61.7, 62.9, 50.1, 56.4, 61.5, 
    56.1, 56.8, 63, 62.9, 32.9, 62.1, 62.6, 65.6, 71.4, 67.2, 
    74.5, 75.5, 79.7), radiation = c(20.4, 22.2, 21.3, 22.4, 
    23.1, 19, 19.7, 20, 19.4, 18.1, 18, 16.9, 16.7, 14.5, 15.2, 
    13.9, 11.3, 9.7, 8.35, 7.17), evapotranspiration = c(0, 0.486, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0286, 0, 0, 0.229, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.257, 
    3.43, 3.2, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

which can be generated like this:

```
Lines <- "
     week             temperature        humidity       radiation    evapotranspiration
2012-03-25               15.9             54.1            20.4            0     
2012-06-17               25.9             65.6            22.2            0.486 
2012-06-24               27.4             61.7            21.3            0     
2012-07-08               27.5             62.9            22.4            0     
2012-07-15               27.5             50.1            23.1            0     
2012-07-22               27.0             56.4            19.0            0     
2012-07-29               28.7             61.5            19.7            0     
2012-08-05               29.1             56.1            20.0            0.0286
2012-08-12               28.6             56.8            19.4            0     
2012-08-19               29.0             63.0            18.1            0     
2012-08-26               27.4             62.9            18.0            0.229 
2012-09-02               16.9             32.9            16.9            0     
2012-09-09               25.0             62.1            16.7            0     
2012-09-16               25.4             62.6            14.5            0     
2012-09-30               22.3             65.6            15.2            0     
2012-10-07               22.4             71.4            13.9            0     
2012-10-14               19.3             67.2            11.3            0.257 
2012-10-21               18.7             74.5            9.70           3.43  
2012-10-28               16.4             75.5            8.35           3.2   
2012-11-04               17.8             79.7            7.17           7"

agroweek <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
agroweek$week <- as.Date(agroweek$week)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have one question, how did you transform the date?

Comment: See expanded Note at end.  In the future please provide the input in reproducible form.

Comment: When I try `width <- seq_along(week) - findInterval(week - 7*k, week)` I get this error: 

Error in findInterval(week - 7 * 6, week) : 
  'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs

Comment: Start a fresh instance of R and then copy the code in the Note and paste it in and then copy the code in (1) and paste it in. The first 6 lines of the output are now shown in the answer so you can see there is no error.   IF you have NAs or the weeks are not ordered then for (1) use na.omit to omit rows with NAs and sort the data.  Note that (2) works even with NAs and even if the data is not sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `rollmean()` from `zoo` and a tidyverse approach with `across()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
#Data
df <- structure(list(week = c("25/03/2012", "17/06/2012", "24/06/2012", 
"08/07/2012", "15/07/2012", "22/07/2012", "29/07/2012", "05/08/2012", 
"12/08/2012", "19/08/2012", "26/08/2012", "02/09/2012", "09/09/2012", 
"16/09/2012", "30/09/2012", "07/10/2012", "14/10/2012", "21/10/2012", 
"28/10/2012", "04/11/2012"), temperature = c(15.9, 25.9, 27.4, 
27.5, 27.5, 27, 28.7, 29.1, 28.6, 29, 27.4, 16.9, 25, 25.4, 22.3, 
22.4, 19.3, 18.7, 16.4, 17.8), humidity = c(54.1, 65.6, 61.7, 
62.9, 50.1, 56.4, 61.5, 56.1, 56.8, 63, 62.9, 32.9, 62.1, 62.6, 
65.6, 71.4, 67.2, 74.5, 75.5, 79.7), radiation = c(20.4, 22.2, 
21.3, 22.4, 23.1, 19, 19.7, 20, 19.4, 18.1, 18, 16.9, 16.7, 14.5, 
15.2, 13.9, 11.3, 9.7, 8.35, 7.17), evapotranspiration = c(0, 
0.486, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0286, 0, 0, 0.229, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.257, 
3.43, 3.2, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

The code:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(temperature:evapotranspiration),
                .fns = list(avg = ~ rollmean(.,k=5,fill=NA,align = 'right')))) -> df2
```

The output:

```
         week temperature humidity radiation evapotranspiration temperature_avg humidity_avg radiation_avg
1  25/03/2012        15.9     54.1     20.40             0.0000              NA           NA            NA
2  17/06/2012        25.9     65.6     22.20             0.4860              NA           NA            NA
3  24/06/2012        27.4     61.7     21.30             0.0000              NA           NA            NA
4  08/07/2012        27.5     62.9     22.40             0.0000              NA           NA            NA
5  15/07/2012        27.5     50.1     23.10             0.0000           24.84        58.88        21.880
6  22/07/2012        27.0     56.4     19.00             0.0000           27.06        59.34        21.600
7  29/07/2012        28.7     61.5     19.70             0.0000           27.62        58.52        21.100
8  05/08/2012        29.1     56.1     20.00             0.0286           27.96        57.40        20.840
9  12/08/2012        28.6     56.8     19.40             0.0000           28.18        56.18        20.240
10 19/08/2012        29.0     63.0     18.10             0.0000           28.48        58.76        19.240
11 26/08/2012        27.4     62.9     18.00             0.2290           28.56        60.06        19.040
12 02/09/2012        16.9     32.9     16.90             0.0000           26.20        54.34        18.480
13 09/09/2012        25.0     62.1     16.70             0.0000           25.38        55.54        17.820
14 16/09/2012        25.4     62.6     14.50             0.0000           24.74        56.70        16.840
15 30/09/2012        22.3     65.6     15.20             0.0000           23.40        57.22        16.260
16 07/10/2012        22.4     71.4     13.90             0.0000           22.40        58.92        15.440
17 14/10/2012        19.3     67.2     11.30             0.2570           22.88        65.78        14.320
18 21/10/2012        18.7     74.5      9.70             3.4300           21.62        68.26        12.920
19 28/10/2012        16.4     75.5      8.35             3.2000           19.82        70.84        11.690
20 04/11/2012        17.8     79.7      7.17             7.0000           18.92        73.66        10.084
   evapotranspiration_avg
1                      NA
2                      NA
3                      NA
4                      NA
5                 0.09720
6                 0.09720
7                 0.00000
8                 0.00572
9                 0.00572
10                0.00572
11                0.05152
12                0.05152
13                0.04580
14                0.04580
15                0.04580
16                0.00000
17                0.05140
18                0.73740
19                1.37740
20                2.77740
```

Comment: Could maybe like to set `partial = TRUE` to take the mean of partial groups.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It is a good approximation but it's not exactly what I need. I just put a comment in the post with some details, could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
cols <- names(df)[-1]
df[, paste0(cols, "_5w_avg") := 
       lapply(.SD, function(x) fcoalesce(frollmean(x, n=5:1, na.rm=TRUE))), 
   .SDcols = cols]
df
#           week temperature humidity radiation evapotranspiration temperature_5w_avg humidity_5w_avg radiation_5w_avg evapotranspiration_5w_avg
#  1: 25/03/2012        15.9     54.1     20.40             0.0000           15.90000        54.10000           20.400              0.000000e+00
#  2: 17/06/2012        25.9     65.6     22.20             0.4860           20.90000        59.85000           21.300              2.430000e-01
#  3: 24/06/2012        27.4     61.7     21.30             0.0000           23.06667        60.46667           21.300              1.620000e-01
#  4: 08/07/2012        27.5     62.9     22.40             0.0000           24.17500        61.07500           21.575              1.215000e-01
#  5: 15/07/2012        27.5     50.1     23.10             0.0000           24.84000        58.88000           21.880              9.720000e-02
#  6: 22/07/2012        27.0     56.4     19.00             0.0000           27.06000        59.34000           21.600              9.720000e-02
#  7: 29/07/2012        28.7     61.5     19.70             0.0000           27.62000        58.52000           21.100              0.000000e+00
#  8: 05/08/2012        29.1     56.1     20.00             0.0286           27.96000        57.40000           20.840              5.720000e-03
#  9: 12/08/2012        28.6     56.8     19.40             0.0000           28.18000        56.18000           20.240              5.720000e-03
# 10: 19/08/2012        29.0     63.0     18.10             0.0000           28.48000        58.76000           19.240              5.720000e-03
# 11: 26/08/2012        27.4     62.9     18.00             0.2290           28.56000        60.06000           19.040              5.152000e-02
# 12: 02/09/2012        16.9     32.9     16.90             0.0000           26.20000        54.34000           18.480              5.152000e-02
# 13: 09/09/2012        25.0     62.1     16.70             0.0000           25.38000        55.54000           17.820              4.580000e-02
# 14: 16/09/2012        25.4     62.6     14.50             0.0000           24.74000        56.70000           16.840              4.580000e-02
# 15: 30/09/2012        22.3     65.6     15.20             0.0000           23.40000        57.22000           16.260              4.580000e-02
# 16: 07/10/2012        22.4     71.4     13.90             0.0000           22.40000        58.92000           15.440             -5.551115e-18
# 17: 14/10/2012        19.3     67.2     11.30             0.2570           22.88000        65.78000           14.320              5.140000e-02
# 18: 21/10/2012        18.7     74.5      9.70             3.4300           21.62000        68.26000           12.920              7.374000e-01
# 19: 28/10/2012        16.4     75.5      8.35             3.2000           19.82000        70.84000           11.690              1.377400e+00
# 20: 04/11/2012        17.8     79.7      7.17             7.0000           18.92000        73.66000           10.084              2.777400e+00
```