# Summarise across rows by making reference to row numbers in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Dear data manipulation wizards,

I am trying to summarize my dataframe in a way that makes reference to row numbers, but I can't find a way to do it in a tidy way. My dataframe looks like this.

```
# Sample data frame.
df <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,1,1,2,4,5,3,2))

  value
1     1
2     2
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     4
7     5
8     3
9     2
```

I need to create a column, which says `TRUE` if the corresponding number in `value` **as well as the numbers in next 4 consecutive rows** are all larger than or equal to 2. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
  value largerThan
1     1      FALSE
2     2      FALSE
3     1      FALSE
4     1      FALSE
5     2       TRUE
6     4         NA
7     5         NA
8     3         NA
9     2         NA
```

Note the four `NA` in the last four rows of `largerThan`. This is because these these rows don't have 4 consecutive rows after them, so they can't be evaluated. This is what is
tripping me up, together with the fact that I don't know how to make reference to row numbers when using `tidyverse` syntax. This was more straightforward with `for loops`, but I can't think of equivalents.

Suggestions are much appreciated! Especially if you have `tidyverse` or `dplyr` solutions, since these are the packages  used in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
df$largerthan <- zoo::rollsum(df$value >= 2, 5, na.pad = T, align = "left") >=5

  value largerthan
1     1      FALSE
2     2      FALSE
3     1      FALSE
4     1      FALSE
5     2       TRUE
6     4         NA
7     5         NA
8     3         NA
9     2         NA
```

Following the logic, a baseR way

```
df$largerthan <- rowSums(cbind(df >=2, c(df[-1,], NA) >=2, c(df[-c(1:2), ], NA, NA) >=2, c(df[-c(1:3),], NA, NA, NA) >=2, c(df[-c(1:4),], NA, NA, NA, NA)>=2)) >=5
```

If you want to do it in dplyr

```
df %>% mutate(largerThan = (value >=2 & lead(value) >=2 & lead(value,2) >= 2 & lead(value, 3) >= 2 & lead(value,4) >= 2))
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about "rollsum". I'll wait to see if someone has an alternative that doesn't require installing a new package, but this already helps a lot. Much appreciated!

Comment: For doing it in base R, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200945/2884859)

Answer (score 1):

sorry, not familiar enough with the tidyverse.. here is a possible `data.table` solution. Perhaps you can transelate it to tidyverse

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df)
df[, largerThan := frollsum( value >= 2, n = 5, align = "left" ) > 4 ]
#    value largerThan
# 1:     1      FALSE
# 2:     2      FALSE
# 3:     1      FALSE
# 4:     1      FALSE
# 5:     2       TRUE
# 6:     4         NA
# 7:     5         NA
# 8:     3         NA
# 9:     2         NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to work out if there is a tidyverse equivalent. It woudl be great if it has something as elegant as this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dpylr` version, however it is less elegant than the other solutions using rollsums. `dpylr` has the functions `lead()` and `lag()`. The solution would look the following way:

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,1,1,2,4,5,3,2))
df = df %>% mutate(
  largerThan = value >= 2 & lead(value) >= 2 & lead(value, 2) >= 2 &
    lead(value, 3) >= 2 & lead(value, 4) >= 2
)
```

As more leads you need, as easier it gets with alternative solutions.